# Docker container port unreachable after Docker host static ip changed

Tags: docker, ip

Host uses CentOS static ip,
Container use Debian system bridge network and map with 80,9101 port to host.

After change host static ip with eth0, the container port cannot be reached remotely, even if recreated. Call from host is ok.
I have to reboot host machine.

Meanwhile, --net host mode container will not be affected.

Comment: The problem is ip_forward=0 in host. i can set 1 to sovle this now~

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you use `--net=host` your port mapping is with docker `-p` is not going to work any more. Because you're exposing your host network to your container.

You can't reach your container port any more because your container's application is actually bound to host IP address upon start up because of `--net=host`, so when the IP gets changed it's not going to work until you restart your application. Then it starts to work again.

If you want temporary solve this issue, either don't use `--net=host` or simply create a iptables rule your self to redirect traffic to your app.

If your app listening to port `8080` and you want to expose it as `80` for example, this should work I guess:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8080

Given that your app is listening to `localhost` as well.

Comment: thanks again.  --net=host is OK. but bridge is affected. the problem is ip_forward=0 in host. i can set 1 to sovle this now~